# Holding down keys combination not working in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, refresh

The code below runs without error in VSC but the action is never carried out. Search bar never pops up on Firefox. (I copied this code from another tutorial site so it's most likely correct). Clicking F5 on the page will also not refresh the page, it basically does nothing. Please help me, thank you.

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
 
# import Action chains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
 
# import KEYS
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 
# create webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 
# get geeksforgeeks.org
driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")
 
# create action chain object
action = ActionChains(driver)
 
# perform the operation
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('F').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

I expected search bar to pop up on Firefox but nothing. No error, no exception. Code executes from beginning to end without a hitch, but no action was carried out.

Comment: I don't think its meant to be used in that way, you need to give it time and feed back. Right now all those commands are happening instantly and firefox has no time to respond.

Comment: I modified the code by adding time.sleep(6) after driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/") but it changes nothing.

Comment: You need to split up the key down and key up. put a sleep between those 2.

Comment: @AaronCloud I've updated it like this:                               
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
time.sleep(2)
action.send_keys('F').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

            . But no find bar pops up. The strange thing is I think that combination scroll down to bottom of the page. When used individually, sending the function keys F{number} don't work either (I tried F3 and F5), but looks like it scroll down to bottom of the page. What do you think the issue is? Thank u

Comment: Can you put the code in a code block for me?